# Add padding to a cell in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have to make invoices with TCPDF. I have a logo on top of the pdf and the title of the company has to come right next to it.

Now i'm doing this:

```
$pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../assets/img/logo.png', 15, 10, 10, 0);
$pdf->Cell(110, 0, 'Company', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 3);
```

But "Company" is on top of the logo now. Is there a way to add padding left on that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../assets/img/logo.png', 15, 10, 10, 0, null, null,'T');
```

[documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352)